# Help golfing this solution further

Tags: code-golf, tips, c#

We are doing a PCG challenge at work, and I'm submitting answers in C#.  This is a modification of the "M'Kay" challenge.  My solution has been deemed correct by the requirements, I'm just trying to shrink it further if possible.

> A filler word is an apparently meaningless word, phrase, or sound that marks a pause or hesitation in speech.
>
> Your task is to create a function that has a 30%-50% chance of adding a random filler word to a block of text after the punctuation marks , ; . ? and !; and when added is followed by the same punctuation. The same filler word must be used for each replacement within a single execution of the function.
>
> If the filler word occurs after a sentence completing punctuation mark such as . ? or ! the filler word must have the first letter capitalized.
>   If the filler word occurs after a sentence pausing punctuation mark such as , or ; the filler word must be in lowercase.
>
> Fillers: um, literally, you know, er, okay, right, ah, like

My submitted code:

```csharp
string p(string i,int z=-1){string w="Um|Literally|You know|Er|Okay|Right|Ah|Like".Split('|')[i.Length %8],s="?,!;.",o="";foreach(var c in i){var x=s.IndexOf(c);o+=(z>0&&i[z]>'9'&&x>-1&&(1&z)<1?c+" "+(x%2>0?" "+w.ToLower():w):"")+c;z++;}return o;}
```

> **Original input text:** We heard tales of Americans like Coast Guard Petty Officer Ashlee Leppert, who is here tonight in the gallery with Melania.  Ashlee was aboard one of the first helicopters on the scene in Houston during Hurricane Harvey.  Through 18 hours of wind and rain, Ashlee braved live power lines and deep water, to help save more than 40 lives.  Thank you, Ashlee.
>
> **With fillers added:** We heard tales of Americans like Coast Guard Petty Officer Ashlee Leppert, *okay*, who is here tonight in the gallery with Melania.  Ashlee was aboard one of the first helicopters on the scene in Houston during Hurricane Harvey. *Okay*.  Through 18 hours of wind and rain, Ashlee braved live power lines and deep water, *okay*, to help save more than 40 lives.  Thank you, Ashlee.

Clarification comments welcome, I don't know what else I need to include.

Comment: You have a redundant space in `[i.Length %8]`, no?

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder dang, yes.  I had problems before with compilation errors in LINQPad and adding the space fixed them.  It runs now without it though.

Comment: Also, I wonder if you could use lambdas (`=>`-functions). I don’t know C# so I cannot tell for sure.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder I think that constitutes an answer on its own...

Comment: "Your task is to create a function that has a 30%-50% chance of adding a random filler word to a block of text after the punctuation marks" would imply to me that 30-50% *of runs* add the filler after *every* punctuation mark.

Comment: There does not seem to be any requirement for any additional spaces, just the filler and trailing punctuation, so you can drop both `" "+` (and I believe the one before `w.ToLower()` is excess to requirements even if adding spaces is required).

Comment: @JonathanAllan: the rules were clarified internally to mean after 30-50% of punctuation marks within a sentence.  The bitmask I'm doing was deemed suitable, because over enough inputs it will average at 50%.

Comment: OK I thought that might be the case. The spec as written is incorrect, it may be worth a little rewording to make it accurate.

Comment: @JonathanAllan: an (actually used internally) example added.

Comment: `z++;` can be incorporated into the `(1&z)<1` check as `(1&z++)<1` unless I'm missing something for 2 bytes, right?

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn: not there anyway, because it bails out early frequently.  I might be able to move it as a precondition check early in the loop though.

Comment: I suggest having a TIO link for testing and avoid lines with too much characters, probably by replacing spaces by newlines whenever possible. That makes code easier to read.

Comment: I think `i[z]>'9'&&x>-1` could maybe become `i[z]>'9'&x>-1`, saving one byte ([TIO](https://tio.run/##LVDRbuIwEPyVxVKDrQQL7umuaUCnUx@QqHoqPVUV4sEyC7FwbGQ7DQnh26mjQ9qH2d2Z0c5KP5HW4a32yhxg3fqAVS618B7@XnwQQcmbD25YnugdqEyZAF0xmbHLfdQU5F/Vr1RAJ7Ru@09bw9HYpn92/etRtP2bOpSh/11GzhEJX5@0CnTcj9lG8RWaQyjh4ec28wVZZKOck8wWhOT7eJqQJf0SDiQoA4pdBnwuPF@aHZ5f91Sy3KYF7ebTJFGbbjsf/xon5/lkliR0lnTsabaQKQGS0vPDj/l0McCGv9uVbdBR9tiwR0JYKvMuTfOrw1A7Aza/3v6nhy@rdvAilLnH32wFu/yxxluN/MPFyCtlkJ4oeS@VB48moJEIEVcoTFTsa81h6UEFMDYs4AO1zoZOogvRWLeRPIK1haqW5eAQ5Schj7gDbyEMr9Mt59EERBVLdLgbEcby6/X2DQ)).

Comment: You can change the `string p(string i,int z=-1)` to a currying lambda: `i=>z=>`. [Here is a TIO on how to do this.](https://tinyurl.com/y92oa5jz)

Comment: Surely you are not going to submit any answers posted here as your own? If so, consider opening your challenge to all languages, not only c#. Also, consider posting your answer in the "answer" box below the question.

Comment: @anatolyg: I'm not going to plagiarize any answer :) This is just for me to learn how to do it better.  Are you suggesting I re-post my answer as an actual captial-A Answer to my own question?

Comment: Yes, I am suggesting that. I also suggest removing the c# tag, so people can answer in any language. You may consider this challenge as your personal c# learning corner, but this is not how stuff works here. It's better to make it everyone's play ground, and let you ignore any answers you want to ignore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> string ... s="?,!;." ... var x=s.IndexOf(c);
> ```

`s` is used only once, so could be inlined.

---

> ```
> var x=s.IndexOf(c); ... &&x>-1&& ... c+" "+(x%2>0?" "+w.ToLower():w):"")+c;
> ```

Change `"?,!;."` to `",;?!."` and the test `x%2>0` can be simplified to `x<2`.

Where in the spec does it require double-space after sentence-terminating punctuation? IMO you could lose the `" "+` inside the parentheses.

---

Given the IMO ridiculous interpretation which they're allowing of "*random*", I don't see why you do such complicated stuff with `z`. Just use the character index modulo 3. A direct change to

```
string p(string i){int n=i.Length,j,x;string w="Um|Literally|You know|Er|Okay|Right|Ah|Like".Split('|')[n%8],o="";for(j=0;j<n;j++){var c=i[j];x=",;.?!".IndexOf(c);o+=(x>-1&&j%3<1?c+" "+(x<2?" "+w.ToLower():w):"")+c;}return o;}
```

gives a further nice saving. An alternative using Linq also saves a lot by exploiting fat arrow syntax, and would be cheaper if they give you free `using` statements:

```
using System.Linq;string p(string s)=>string.Join("",s.Select((c,i)=>{var w="Um|Literally|You know|Er|Okay|Right|Ah|Like".Split('|')[s.Length%8];var x=",;.?!".IndexOf(c);return(x>=0&&i%3<1?c+" "+(x<2?" "+w.ToLower():w):"")+c;}));
```